# How to input byte array to a function?

Tags: bytes

I have a function in my contract and it have bytes1[4] array parameter and returns.

```
function foo(bytes1[4] memory _mdata) public pure returns(bytes1[4]){
    bytes1[4] memory result;
    uint8 i;
    for(i=0 ; i<4 ; i++){
        result[i] = _mdata[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

And in my truffle test javascript, it have something like..

```
var myData = [0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x1f];
it("test", async() => {
    let instant = await myArithmetic.deployed();
    let result = await instant.foo(myData);
    console.log(result);
```

I got `[ '0x10', '0x20', '0x30', '0x1f' ]` Is this because of different endian between javascript and solidty compiler? But why the last one returned correctly??

Comment: I know endian is related to the byte order not 4-bits.  Is it bug on truffle or solidity?

Comment: If you pass `["0x01", "0x02", "0x03", "0x1f"]` does it work? I often have problems with javascript function when you pass a number but it expect a string. To be safe everything bytesXX seems to require a string.

Comment: It works fine with `["0x01", "0x02", "0x03", "0x1f"]` !! Thank you.