# Understanding Bytes16 Representation in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle-contract, bytes

I have a simple function printing byte a byte the value of a bytes16 0x20010db8000000000000000000000001 and I get the following result.

['0x20', '0x01', '0x0d', '0xb7', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0x65' ]

[ '0x20', '0x7e', '0x22', '0x36', '0x66', '0xc0', '0x00', '0x00' ]

It should not be??

['0x20', '0x01', '0x0d', '0xb8', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00' ]

[ '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0x01' ]

Why it is not??

Here the code:

```
function print1(bytes16 a) public 
returns (bytes1,bytes1,bytes1,bytes1,bytes1,bytes1,bytes1,bytes1){
return (a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6],a[7]);}


function print2(bytes16 a) public returns
(bytes1,bytes1,bytes1,bytes1,bytes1,bytes1,bytes1,bytes1){
return (a[8],a[9],a[10],a[11],a[12],a[13],a[14],a[15]);}
```

Step to reproduce:

```
print1(0x20010db8000000000000000000000001);
print2(0x20010db8000000000000000000000001);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code with Remix. But it works fine. 
If you tested using truffle (javascript test file), then you should use print1("0x20010db8000000000000000000000001"), do not forget "". 
I got similar issue with byte1 array as [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47309/how-to-input-byte-array-to-a-function).

[image]

And this is truffle result with your code,

[image]

plus, both print1 and print2, you better add "pure" to avoid warning, something like..

```
function print1(bytes16 a) public pure
```

Comment: OK that is fine but Why??

Comment: @StefanoAngieri I am not sure, but it need to explicitly require " " to pass string, bytes, address except number.